# Build a App that accepts language pack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I'm quite lost here and I need guidance.

I need to build a web app that will support language packs... the idea is to start with a default language such as English, and then the client will be able to download a language pack and install it and then choose between the default language and any other installed language. Are there any patterns on the matter? Maybe a open source software I could study (and take as an example)? Or maybe some literature on it?

**Edit1:** The idea here is that the user will deploy the web app on premises (or cloud IaaS) and install as many language packs as are available, and the app would check the browser language and check if there's a compatible language pack to translate to... .Net already does that using localized resources files, that require recompilation...

Comment: a simple Google search for "mvc multilingual application" returned a bunch of good tutorials and articles.

Comment: @Rob the search returned a bunch of examples based on resources files...

Comment: When you say language pack, where would the user download it from? Is this so that the web app can be viewed in multiple languages?

Comment: @Rob The user would download from my website and your second question I answered in "Edit1"

Comment: Is the idea that you want the client to be able to do the translation from English to another language? Or are you just trying to avoid redeploying the web app after adding support for more languages using resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from the unix world is gettext, but I bet you're looking for something a little more modern.

At the bottom of it, you have to structure your string-consuming code to use members to read what strings to handle/print/etc, eg, `this.mainForm.Title = StringLib.MainFormTitle`.

StringLib would be just a big static class with a ton of get/set properties.

Then, create separate assemblies for each language you wish to support, name them something like langpack.en-US.dll, langpack.it-IT.dll, etc. Each would contain two classes - one class that you would instantiate to get metadata about the language pack (culture, version, etc) and another class, that when so invoked, filles in your StringLib class's static properties.

At run-time, look for all langpack files, then use reflection to load them. Use reflection to figure out the name of the lang pack, present those in a list for the user to select from. The user selects a langpack, at which point you invoke the initializer class in the lang pack. The initializer makes a ton of calls to init the StringLib class's properties, and off you go.

In MainApp.csproj:

```
public class StringLib {
    public static string MainFormTitle { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In langpack.en-US.csproj:

```
public class LangPackDescriptor : ILangPackDescriptor { 
    public readonly string LangPackName = "American English";
    public readonly string CultureString = "en-US";
    ...
}

public class EnUsLangPackInit : ILangPackInit { 
    public void Init() {
        StringLib.MainFormTitle = "My Application Name"
        ...
    }
}
```

In langpack.it-IT.csproj

```
public class LangPackDescriptor : ILangPackDescriptor { 
    public static string LangPackName = "Italian";
    public string string CultureString = "it-IT";
    ...
}

public class ItItLangPackInit : ILangPackInit{ 
    public void Init() {
        StringLib.MainFormTitle = "Il Nome Del Mio Applicazione"
        ...
    }
}
```

Using reflection to initalize, given a filename:

```
public void LoadLang(string filename) {
   Assembly langpackAssembly;
   ILangPackDescriptor descriptor;
   ILangPackInit initializer;

   langpackAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);

   Type[] langpackTypes = langpackAssembly.GetExportedTypes();

   foreach( Type foundType in langpackTypes ) {
        if ( foundType.GetInterfaces().Contains<Type>( typeof(ILangPackDescriptor) ) ) {
            descriptor = Activator.CreateInstance(foundType);
        }

        if ( foundType.GetInterfaces().Contains<Type>( typeof(ILangPackInit) ) ) {
            initializer = Activator.CreateInstance(foundType);
        }
   }

   // If the passed-in file was the langpack.en-US.dll file, then this 
   // calls langpack.en-US.dll's EnUsLangPackInit.Init() method.
   initializer.Init();
}
```